# What does "a stock pays a dividend of 3%" mean?

Tags: stocks, dividends

Does it mean the company pays 3% of the total earnings to the stock holders? So if I have a stock that has 1$ EPS I would receive 3 cents?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It means a 3% return on the value of the stock. If a stock has a $10 share price, the dividend would be $0.30.

Normally though, the dividends are announced as a fixed amount per share, because the share price fluctuates. If a percentage were announced, then the final cost would not be known as the share priced could change radically before the dividend date.

Comment: Clarification - aren't dividends stated and issued quarterly? e.g. A $1 dividend per year announced as $.25.

Comment: There can be any number of dividends per year, but typical practice is four quarterly dividends of equal amounts.  The __yield__, which is what "a dividend of 3%" is called, is always given as an annual percentage of the current price.  Since the price fluctuates daily, the yield (dividend percentage) also fluctuates daily.

Comment: @mgkrebbs actually that depends on the county and company 2 dividends a year is common in the UK- its only some of the big Investment trusts that do quarterly